# Charger for my own created battery pack

Tags: batteries, charger, nimh

I am building an RC airplane, for which I have also created a battery pack. What kind of charger do I need to power up the simple line-up of:
6 x AAA, 1.2v, 800mah per battery. (Everything is lined up in serie, non-parallel)
The batteries I have ordered are NiMH, I don't know if it matters.

What should I take into account with buying a charger? Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[iMAX B6AC](https://www.pololu.com/file/download/iMAXB6ACmanual.pdf?file_id=0J525) can do what you need and it's also good for other chemistries if you'll make other types of battery packs in the future.